# How to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo in WPF 4.5?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, inotifydataerrorinfo

I realized that appears this interface in .NET Framework 4.5

I was looking first for about how to implemented in Silverlight (I can imagine that it's implemented in the same way), but I can't find a compact demo of this new interface. Is it possible to show how can I use it?

I really want to find a small demo to understand it

Comment: Can't you use the same implementation example on the MSDN page for the Silverlight version? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Beside the very detailed description on MSDN about the [Silverlight version of INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

There are already some blog posts with samples how to use/implement it in WPF 4.5:

- WPF 4.5 – Asynchronous validation [(original link no longer working)](http://burnaftercoding.com/post/asynchronous-validation-with-wpf-4-5/) [Wayback Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190209072409/http://burnaftercoding.com/post/asynchronous-validation-with-wpf-4-5/)
- [WPF 4.5 – Part 1 : Asynchronous data validation](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/18/wpf-4-5-asynchronous-data-validation/) (the author has a [nice series](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/20/wpf-4-5-is-here-check-out-the-new-features/) about the new fetaures in WPF 4.5)

Comment: First link is not working!

Answer (score 0):

The [PRISM library](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) has a very good example implementation in the MVVM RI sample, the class named [DomainObject](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/65392#1007560) implements both INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyDataErrorInfo.

It is a SL version but it now compiles with .NET 4.5

Comment: but that one just work on Silverlight, doesn't it?

Comment: @DarfZon now it works with WPF (4.5)
 I am currently using it. You just need DomainObject.cs and ErrorContainer.cs