# Methods of validation in WPF, MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have been told there are many ways you can do validation in WPF + MVVM that belong in the ViewModel. What is the best (good) method of doing validation? Any links or examples would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want? Windows **Driver** Foundation (WDF) or Windows **Presentation** Fondation (WPF)

Comment: Sorry, your right, a spelling error. Its WPF, (XAML) I will update. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo or IDataErrorInfo (.NET < 4.5).

Question about INofiryDataErrorInfo:
[SO INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950128/how-to-implement-inotifydataerrorinfo-in-wpf-4-5)

Article about IDataErrorInfo:
[IDataErrorInfo](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/10/02/data-validation-in-3-5.aspx)